# makeindex: first letter bold

Tags: makeindex

I create my index with makeindex, my .ist-file looks like that:

```
% sty.file for mkidx32.exe - redefines:
quote '+'
headings_flag 0
%headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak%\n \\indexspace\\nopagebreak%"
delim_0 ": "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 ": "
%delim_r "~--~"
delim_r "-"
%delim_0 "\\dotfill "
%delim_1 "\\dotfill "
%delim_2 "\\dotfill "
%delim_r "~--~"
suffix_2p "\\,f."
suffix_3p "\\,ff."
```

The publishers guidelines say "no index letters", so I've set headings_flag to 0, which works as expected.
But the guidelines also require the first letter of each first entry to be bold, like:

**A**aaa
Abc
Adddd
Affff

**B**ar
Brrr
Buuu

...and I have no idea how to realize that... any idea appreciated.

edit:
Sorry, the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}

%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\blindtext\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And pls note I added:
`\usepackage[indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}`
for configuring the indention.

I also tried to set the first letter of each first entry bold manually (like `\index{\textbf{A}aronsen, John}`. Generally, this works, but I got a bigger line spacing after this first entry, which isn't an option...

Comment: this will probably only work because you modify the `*.ist` file local on your system. the minute you turn in your `*.tex` files, this won't work at all.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it would be okay in this case as I have to deliver the final PDF file. So a modification of the ist file is probably the way to go in here... any help for that would be highly appreciated

Comment: see if the answer in this forum helps: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8096

Comment: Unrelated, since you have the headings switched off, but the `heading_prefix` value is incorrect. It should be to `"\\textbf{"` or ` `"{\\bfseries "`` not `"{\\textbf "`. I recommend you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with a few indexed examples as people are more likely to answer questions if they can copy and paste a small but complete test document to work on. (Scroll down the to Index section of [the MWE answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for examples.)

Comment: Sorry, forget that yesterday, here's a minimal working example:
`\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}  
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
    \usepackage{makeidx}  
    \makeindex  
    \begin{document}  
    text\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}.  
    \printindex  
    \end{document}`

Comment: arguments for makeindex, set in texniccenter:  
`"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind" -l -s register.ist`  
register.ist contains the code mentioned in original post.

In my original version, headings_flag was set to 1:   https://www.screencast.com/t/z4IeahcOyIaJ  
then I set headings_flag to 0:  
https://www.screencast.com/t/G4srXdma
much better, but in here the A of Aronson and the B of Baily should be bold...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fail if some “first entry” has accented characters:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
quote '+'
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\firstentry "
heading_suffix ""
delim_0 ": "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 ": "
%delim_r "~--~"
delim_r "-"
%delim_0 "\\dotfill "
%delim_1 "\\dotfill "
%delim_2 "\\dotfill "
%delim_r "~--~"
suffix_2p "\\,f."
suffix_3p "\\,ff."
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\def\firstentry#1\item#2{\item\textbf{#2}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I have used the MakeIndex feature that it will look for a file named `<main>.mst` and use it as the style file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great! Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it, I always get this: https://www.screencast.com/t/97CbLrZSyOEV
Probably I didn't configure the .ist / .mst-usage correctly.  
I still use "%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind" -l -s register.ist in TexnicCenter - how would the proper setting be in this case? In the register.ist file, I have implemented the code of your "jobname.mst".  
I just don't get it at the moment...and think I have something essential missed in here. Could you please explain your settings a bit more detailed?

Comment: @binsky Sorry, a backslash got mangled in the `.mst` file, where it should be `\\firstentry`.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggested solution and the additional comment. this works absolutely perfect!